# Hibernate multithreading slows my application down

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, hibernate

I am working on data visualization. I have a MySQL database, java backend, js front end. I access the DB via Hibernate.
I need to retrieve a couple of mio. rows from the DB at a time in order to visualize them properly.

**Initial problem: it takes about 20-30 seconds for the whole process**

This is not very user-friendly so I need to reduce that time!
I looked where the long waiting time is coming from, and it is definitely the data receiving from the DB: when I want to retrieve the same data in MySQLWorkbench with pure SQL instead of Hibernate it takes almost the same time.

So data processing in the backend is **not the problem**, it is getting the data in the first place.

I tried to tackle this problem with multithreading.
I read about the common problems using multithreading with hibernate and tried to avoid them, but still I have the feeling I am overlooking something important.

**Here is what i tried so far:**
In the method which should return all the data for further processing I have

```
 some code...
 for(int i = 0; i <= numberOfThreads; i++) {
     Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
             try{
                 someDataStructure = HibernateUtil.executeHqlCustom(hql, 
                       lowerLimit, stepSize);
             }catch(someException){
                  ...
             }
        }
     };
     r.run();
     r = null;
 }
 return someDataStructure;
```

The "executeHqlCustom" creates a session, creates a Query, uses the **setFirstResult** to set the lower bound and uses the **setMaxResult** to set the amount of data each thread should be responsible of (this way the data should be received in chunks).
Session gets closed.

I tried a lot of different combinations (from a couple of threads up to 1 thread for every single row in the DB (what is ridiculous I know!)) but in the end using no multi threading was always faster than all other options I just described.

I also tried using an own class which implements Runnable / extends Thread and had a boolean flag as an instance variable in order to set the thread to null when it is not needed anymore.

None of that was any better.

Like I said I am 99% sure I am overlooking something very important or that I misunderstood some of the concepts of multithreading (I am very new to that).

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You can't solve an I/O bottleneck with multithreading. The threads will just compete for the same I/O "power". If you have a long line to the toilet, you don't solve that by putting more doors on it.

Comment: I see thank you. Do you have any advice how to tackle the long loading problem?

Comment: Don't load it all before you start processing it. Load the data in a more efficient form. Scale up or out for more processing power.

Comment: Other things to consider are: 1) streaming results (or loading smaller batches of results from the frontend) to give the user some feedback more quickly, even if it still takes the same amount of time to get the full data. and 2) cache your data before the user asks for it so that you don't have to do a DB lookup at all.

Comment: limiting your query with (owerLimit, stepSize) is not necessarily going to speed up your query execution. It depends on the presence of indexes 
 on the columns present in the where clause.

Comment: If you're needing to visualize several million rows, my suggestion would be to aggregate what you need to visualize offline and simply allow your UI to use that pre-aggregated data-set.  You could always sync the aggregated data-set on some short interval, every 5 minutes but at least your user experience would be far better at the cost of delayed updates.

Comment: Is "mio" million or thousand?  I have a hard time imagining that you tried it with millions of simultaneous threads.

Comment: @AlejandroC. the problem with streaming is that then I would need to re-render the visualization all the time because it depends on the whole dataset ..... I thought about cache too but wasnt too excited about it due to the fact that the data set grows quit fast and one wants to see the new results imediatly...but at the end i think i cant avoid to use some sort of offline storage anyway...

Comment: @Naros do you mean cache aswell? if not could you explain in a bit more detail what you mean? :) would be helpfull

Comment: I assumed your query was doing some type of expensive joins or aggregate function calls (min/max/avg/etc) across your data-set and you were trying to visualize the aggregated data-set.  What i was suggesting was that if that is true, trying to eliminate those by running the aggregate query in a background job and store/cache the result in a table that your application/view uses to render the results.  I find it hard you need to visualize thousands or even millions of individual rows in a single view as that seems over kill for any user.